# How to automatically generate custom id's in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'd like to manage my own `_id`'s through Mongoose/MongoDB - as the default ones are pretty long and consume bandwidth.

The difficulty is that I need to create them (say, by incrementing a counter), but I need to do this in a concurrent environment (Node.JS). Is there a simple example I could follow that creates a schema, with a custom `_id` and a static method (or anything better) that automatically generates the next unique `_id`, whenever a new document is created?

Comment: Is the length of the ID seriously the bottleneck of your application? I highly doubt that. The best way to do it is with a uuid system, which MongoDB does for you.

Comment: While this is a good point, OP's reason is not the only possible one and the question is definitely valid. E.g. in our case we need to have user-friendly IDs for a lot of the entities in the application, and these IDs have to be unique and mandatory as well, basically playing the role of _id. So while there is hardly anything more maintainable than uuid, it's ugliness is surely a drawback. The official advice from Mongo team btw is not to use extra fields in such cases, rather override _id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Mongo's findAndModify() to generate sequential values. Below is an example of this:

```
// (assuming db is a reference to a MongoDB database)
var counters = db.collection('counters');
var query = {'name': 'counterName'};
var order = [['_id','asc']];
var inc = {$inc:{'next':1}};
var options = {new: true, upsert: true};
counters.findAndModify(query, order, inc, options, function(err, doc) {

  if(err) {
    callback(err);
    return;
  }      

  var id = doc.next;
  callback(null, id);
});
```

Although generating sequential IDs looks pretty on applications keep in mind that there are some drawbacks to them (e.g. when you need to split your database geographically) which is why Mongo uses the long pseudo-random keys that it does.

Answer (score 3):

As Chad briefly touched on, Mongo implements a uuid system for you, taking into account the timestamp, network address, and machine name, plus an autoincrementing 2 digit counter (in the event that multiple entries with the same timestamp occur). This schema is used to allow distributed databases (ie, running different database instances on different machines) while ensuring that each entry will still have a unique identifier (because the machine name section will be different).

Trying to role out your own schema would likely greatly limit the scalability that mongo provides.

Comment: Chad and you have a point, especially for geographically dispersed systems. This being said, my app needs to serve large quantities of (small) documents to client browsers and carry a few `_id`s in each of them. Replacing 24 characters by only a couple would greatly reduce the traffic. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: My thoughts are that with modern tech, the trade off of saving the (extremely small) bandwidth isn't really worth the inability to scale. If you are 100% certain that you will never need to scale out, and that your traffic will always be low enough to be handled by one machine, you can do your own. Chances are though it is not worth it. You could calculate the bandwidth costs you would save, however I doubt it would even be worth your time, let alone the other tradeoffs I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
import { randomString } from '@/helpers'

const taskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        default: randomString
    },
    title: String,
    ...
})
```

Random string function

```
// helpers

export const randomString = (length?: number) => {
    let result = ''
    const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
    const charactersLength = characters.length
    const n = length || 15
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength))
    }

    return result
}
```

Tested result

```
{ "_id": "EIa9W2J5mY2lMDY", ... }
```